# Changed parameter in for loop but returns same numbers(Python)

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, append

can anyone point out the problem in this code that causes the list to end up with the same elements?

```
numbers = []

def add_tolist(x,y):
i = 0
for i in range(x):
    numbers.append(i)

i += y
for num in numbers:
    print num
```

add_tolist(10,1) returns the same numbers in the list as add_tolist(10,2)

I have a feeling its something really obvious that I am overlooking.

Comment: You should check your indentations. At least after you c/p here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to assign a value to `i` and increment it like in C. In python `for-in` statement is kind of different. You should check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm) or [this](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).
About range and its steppings, you should check [this](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#range)

Using all of those, I think this is what you want to achieve.

```
numbers = []

def add_tolist(x,y):
    for i in range(0,x,y):
        numbers.append(i)

    for num in numbers:
        print (num)

>>> add_tolist(10,2)
0 2 4 6 8

>>> add_tolist(10,1)
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with y until after you've already created the list of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your original indentation got lost.
If not: (The program shouldn't even run, if not...)

```
def add_tolist(x,y):
i = 0
for i in range(x):
    numbers.append(i)
```

This doesn't use the parameter y.

```
i += y
```

is at the same indentation level as numbers = []

What did you expect it to do?